# How to use RecyclerView inside a nested scroll view in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollbar, navigation-drawer

[Update] Added the style and the whole layout

I'm having a RecyclerView inside NavigationView but it's not scrolling to display the whole list of items. I tried using NestedScrollView as described in an answer but it didn't work

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/herdchatHerdsNestedSV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/cats_recycler_view"
            style="@style/catsRrecyclerView"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

but this way didn't work so I'm trying this method now

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/cats_recycler_view"
            style="@style/catsRrecyclerView"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"/>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Style

```
<style name="catsRrecyclerView">
    <item name="android:layout_below">@id/pages_layout</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbars">vertical</item>
</style>
```

The whole layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/cats_recycler_view"
        style="@style/catsRrecyclerView"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"/>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/loading_indicator"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/notification_textView"
        android:id="@+id/notification_view"
        android:text="No Data Found" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pages_layout"
        style="@style/pages_layout">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next_page"
            style="@style/prev_page.next_page"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/page_number"
            style="@style/page_number"
            android:text="Page 1"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/prev_page"
            style="@style/prev_page" />



    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        style="@style/recyclerView" />

  </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

the vertical scrollbar is visible but it's not scrolling. What's the problem here and how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe your adapter layout root container has `height` set to `match_parent`?

Comment: which element height should be wrap_content?

Comment: root container of your layout used in adapter should have `height` set to `wrap_content`

Comment: Can you post `@style/catsRrecyclerView` please?

Comment: style added please check

Comment: @Yupi please advise how to edit the <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView code to make it scroll? its height is set to wrap_content as well ass the recyclerview

Comment: @PHPUser try the solution I suggested and see if it works.

Comment: You didn't get me. The adapter which you set to your `recycler view` you inflated layout inside that adapter check that layout provided to adapter, does it has root view which `height` is set to `match_parent`? Or post your adapter layout as well

Comment: all are wrap_content now and still not working. the list item root, NavigationView and RecyclerView

Comment: added the whole layout code please check

Comment: Do you have `adapter` which you set to the `recyclerview`? like for example: `cats_recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: yes sure: catsRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

Comment: when I display the device on my pc and use the mouse scroll I find that the recyclerview is scrolling but not when I use swipe action (scrolling) on the real device!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The issue was placing the NavigationView at the top of the layout just below the root. Changing the position to the end of the layout after other views made it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the height of RecyclerView's direct parent to `wrap_content` :)

In the first example:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/herdchatHerdsNestedSV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The height of this one -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/cats_recycler_view"
            style="@style/catsRrecyclerView"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Or in the second example (be warned that this might cause unpredictable results when the list is smaller than the screen size since your root view is not matching the parent in height):

```
<!-- The height of this one -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/cats_recycler_view"
            style="@style/catsRrecyclerView"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"/>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

See if it helps?

Comment: I tried NavigationView but stil doesn't work. the first example has an issue because it's not displaying the content in the drawer but in the main layout don't know why. is there any conflict with another recyclerview in the main layout or just height issue? it's wrap_content now and still not scrolling

Comment: can you please provide a working example of a RecyclerView inside DrawerView?